# Game Center Leaderboard/Achievement title language always English on IOS 7

Tags: ios7, leaderboard

When the system language change into french, but the language of title and description for leaderboard( or achievement) can not be changed, always English.
And this issue only happens on IOS7(IOS6 is OK.) Here is my code,

```Objective-C
- (void) showLeaderboard
{
    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    if (gameCenterController != nil)
    {
        gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
        gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
        UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
        UIViewController* rootViewController = window.rootViewController;
        [rootViewController presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
    }
    [gameCenterController release];
}
```

Now, this codes are working on IOS6, so any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think apps cache Leaderboard titles, so switching languages while an app is running causes the previous language title to display.

See my detailed post: [Wrong language in Game Center Leaderboards/Achievements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845059/wrong-language-in-game-center-leaderboards-achievements/29271782#29271782)