# Wrong language in Game Center Leaderboards/Achievements

Tags: ios, game-center

The device language is Italian, when I open the Game Center from my app the titles "leaderboard" "achievement" are in Italian but the names and description of leaderboards  and achievements are in English!!

I use this code to show it :

```
GameKitHelper *gkHelper = [GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper];
[gkHelper showLeaderboard];
```

If I open the Game Center directly from the app Game Center is everything in Italian.

Answer (score 0):

Your app should follow the language settings that are set at a device level, not at an app level. You cant force game/app kit into another language, the user needs to change their language in the settings.

Comment: but my device language is just wetted in italian! I don't understand why I see them in english

Comment: Check app language that you selected in Game Center(In Your iTunes Account). Is it Eng or italic ?

Comment: in iTunes Connect I have english as primary localized language and then italian....

Comment: I try...but it's the same

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a running app caches the localised Leaderboard titles.  If you leave the app running and switch languages, when you return to the app, the Leaderboard view uses the previous language's titles.  I have 4 languages in my app so I noticed the pattern fairly quickly.

Sadly very few developers have bothered with translations of the Leaderboards.  So the only app I could find was Zen Pinball for iPad, it confirmed this behaviour. I think this is an iOS bug but I'm not going to work around this as very few users would be inconvenienced.